# What is the goal of declaring an array with an offset? [8:1] instead of [7:0]

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

What is the goal of declaring an array with an offset? `[8:1]` instead of `[7:0]`

I'm used to declare my signals with `reg [7:0] sig;` for an 8b signal.

Declaring `reg [8:1] sig;` or even `reg [1008:1000] sig;` gives the same value with `sig = 1; $display("sig=%d", sig);`

What's the purpose of defining them like that? Is there any disadvantage on calculation(mismatch)? Especially when used with other signals starting from 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the logic you want to create that addresses each individual bit (you might want to read this article on [Big-Endian versus Little-Endian](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/big-endian-and-little-endian). If you don't need to select individual bits, then the ordering and start bit is completely arbitrary.

If you are designing a positioning system, then it might even make sense to have negative indexes.

Comment: Understood, thank you, then `sig` will always be seen as just an 8bits "variable" as long as I don't access individual bit. The endianness is quite different, it'd be more `[7:0] vs [0:7]`.